# How to create an installer project in VS2019 for a Windows form application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer

I have a very simple Windows Forms application (not the one with the .NET Framework) and I want to make an installer for it. The problem is that whenever I'm trying to run the installed application, it displays an error saying that it requires .NET Core to run, even if it's already installed. I tried including everything from the project output folder, including .exe and .dll files, but that doesn't seem to work. [Here's how installer project files look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MwrR.png)

Answer (score 2):

Please check out my nanny-level teaching！

Environment：

[image]

1.Add Enxtention:
[image]

2.Install Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project：
[image]

3.Closs the ide to start installing:

[image]

[image]

[image]

4.Create a setup project:

[image]

[image]

5.Modify the information as needed:

[image]

6.Right click Setup (Application Folder) > add > file > (all the file)：
[image]

[image]

7.Then create a shortcut, cut it to User Desktop and, after creating a shortcut, put it in User Program:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

8.Build：
[image]

[image]

8.Install and run:

[image]